# For each $n,n>0$ let $a_n$ be the number of points of intersection of the graph $y =\sin x$ with line $y= x/n$. Then the sequence $a_n$ is :

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For each positive number $n$ let $a_n$ be the number of points of intersection of the graph $y =\sin x$ with line $y= x/n$. Then the sequence $a_n$ is :

(a) decreasing

(b) converging to zero

(c) diverging to infinity

I feel that answer should be (c) because as $n \to \infty$ , slope of the line keeps on decreasing untill it reaches $0$ when $n \to \infty$ , also

for $y =0$ ie $sinx =0$ has infinite number of intersection points (solutions) hence answer should be

(c)

Is my answer and reasoning correct ?

Comment: slope never reaches $0$. It approaches $0$, and this is good enough to justify that the answer is (c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. To justify it more rigorously, think about the number of fixed points of the function $n\sin x$ on the interval $[-n, n]$. It's about $\frac{n}{\pi}$.